# Build an example of a topological space $A$ such that $H_4(A;\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Build an example of a topological space $A$ such that
>   $$H_n(A;\mathbb{Z})= \begin{cases}
>              \mathbb{Z} &  \text{ if  } n=0 \\
>              \mathbb{Z}/2 & \text{ if } n=4 \\
>              0 & \text{ otherwise} 
>              \end{cases}.$$

Since $H_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}$ then $A$ has to be arc-connected, I've thought about using Mayer Vietoris's succession to build this example 
$$...\to H_4(U\cap V)\to H_4(U)\oplus H_4(V)\to H_4(A)\to H_3(U\cap V)\to H_3(U)\oplus H_3(V)\to...$$
but I do not know how to take $U\subset A$ and $V\subset A$ or how can I do this, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I want to say $S^3\mathbb{R}P^2$, and $S^3\mathbb{R}P^2=SSS\mathbb{R}P^2$ where $SX$ is the suspension of space $X$.

Answer (score 6):

Since $H_0(\Bbb R\Bbb P^2;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z$ and $H_1(\Bbb R\Bbb P^2;\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ you can just suspend this space a few times.

More generally suppose $G=\langle R | S\rangle$ is a group presentation for an Abelian $G$, you can build a $2$-dimensional connected CW-complex $X$ with $H_1(X;\Bbb Z)=G$ by picking a wedge of as many $S^1$ as elements of $R$, orienting each circle, and attaching one $2$-cell for every relation in $S$, "along the relation".

Suspending such a space gives a space with only one nontrivial prescribed homology group, and wedging together many such spaces is a way to build a space with prescribed homology in every dimension.

Comment: To clarify: there is a natural isomorphism $H_{i+1}( \sum X) = \overset{\~}{H}_i(X)$ for all i, thus there is a natural isomorphism $H_{i+m}( \sum^m X) = \overset{\~}{H}_i(X)$ for $m \geq 0$.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti 
In this case I realize that $A=SSS\mathbb{R}P^2$ with what you just said, because in this case $H_0(SSS\mathbb{R}P^2)$ for being arc-connected and also $H_4(SSS\mathbb{R}P^2)=H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$. But I can not see why $H_n(SSS\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$ for $n\neq 0$ and $n\neq 4$. How can I prove this for these cases?

Comment: You can think about the suspension of $X$ as two cones over $X$ glued together and do a Mayer-Vietoris argument to get something like $H_k(X)\to H_k(CX)\oplus H_k(CX)\to H_k(SX)$, this gets annoying in dimension zero, so it's better to look at reduced homology (relative to a point)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti 
If I were to calculate $H_3(S^3\mathbb{R}P^2)$, then I get to $H_3(S^3\mathbb{R}P^2)=H_2(S^2\mathbb{R}P^2)=H_1(S\mathbb{R}P^2)=\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}P^2)$, so I know that $H_0(X;R)\cong \widetilde{H_0}(X;R)\oplus R$, so $\mathbb{Z}\cong \widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}P^2)\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, so I can conclude then that $\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$? Why? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Take $S^4$ as a cell complex and glue a disk $D^5$ so that $f:\partial D^4 \to S^4$ is a map of degree $2$. To show that such a map exists, you might need some suspension argument as above.

Then by using cellular homology, the complex is
$$0 \to \mathbb  Z \to_{\times 2}\mathbb Z \to 0 \dots \to 0 \to \mathbb  Z \to 0.$$

Comment: If I were to calculate $H_3(S^33\mathbb{R}P^2)$, then I get to $H_3(S^3\mathbb{R}P^2)=H_2(S^2\mathbb{R}P^2)=H_1(S\mathbb{R}P^2)=\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}P^2)$, so I know that $H_0(X;R)≅\widetilde{H_0}(X;R)⊕R$, so $\mathbb{Z}≅\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}P^2)⊕\mathbb{Z}$, so I can conclude then that $\widetilde{H_0}(\mathbb{R}P^2)=0$? Why? Thank you!

Comment: I want to say $S^3\mathbb{R}P^2$, and $S^3\mathbb{R}P^2=SSS\mathbb{R}P^2$ where $SX$ is the suspension of space $X$.